# JavaScript add values to object in object

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm currently programming an Angular nvD3 chart for my temperature sensors.

I have the following data variable:

```
var data = [
        {
            key: 'Pt #1',
            values: [{x: "04.10.2016", y: 14 },{x: "05.10.2016", y: 16 },{x: "06.10.2016", y: 15 },{x: "07.10.2016", y: 16 }]
        },
        {
            key: 'PT #2',
            values: [{x: "04.10.2016", y: 39 },{x: "05.10.2016", y: 40 },{x: "06.10.2016", y: 47 },{x: "07.10.2016", y: 22 }]
        },
        {
            key: 'PT #3',
            values: [{x: "04.10.2016", y: 22 },{x: "05.10.2016", y: 23 },{x: "06.10.2016", y: 22 },{x: "07.10.2016", y: 43 }]
        },
        {
            key: 'PT #4',
            values: [{x: "04.10.2016", y: 25 },{x: "05.10.2016", y: 22 },{x: "06.10.2016", y: 23 },{x: "07.10.2016", y: 12 }]
        },
        {
            key: 'PT #5',
            values: [{x: "04.10.2016", y: 17 },{x: "05.10.2016", y: 17 },{x: "06.10.2016", y: 16 },{x: "07.10.2016", y: 37 }]
        },
        {
            key: 'PT #6',
            values: [{x: "04.10.2016", y: 24 },{x: "05.10.2016", y: 24 },{x: "06.10.2016", y: 25 },{x: "07.10.2016", y: 43 }]
        },
        {
            key: 'PT #7',
            values: [{x: "04.10.2016", y: 11 },{x: "05.10.2016", y: 12 },{x: "06.10.2016", y: 11 },{x: "07.10.2016", y: 11 }]
        }
];
```

Since the data inside the data object has to be added automatically by an later written script, I'd like to know how I can access and add data to the certain key# inside the data variable.

For Example i want to add the next day and its temperatures to key 'PT #1' with the values "08.10.2016" and a temperature from that day without deleting the others, how can I do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you try anything? You should show what you have tried, that's the best way for us to help you figure where it went wrong. You'll learn more than if I just write the code for you

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would iterate your `array of objects` and find corresponding `key`, and then manipulate values of the `object`, something like below:

```
data.forEach(function(item) {
    if(item.key === 'Pt #1'){
        item.values.forEach(function(subItem) {
           console.log("subItem", subItem);
           if(subItem.y == '14') {
               subItem.x = '08.10.2016'
           }
        });
    }
});
```

Below is the fiddle for the same:

https://jsfiddle.net/r85hkpdw/

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

you could simply go through the array (data) by using 'forEach' and upon check of each item find if its key matches the key you're after. if so, push to that item's 'values' the new object to the array of objects

```
var newObj = { x: "08.10.2016", y: 34 };

data.forEach(item => {
    if (item.key === 'Pt #1') item.values.push(newObj)
});
```

Comment: notice your key is actually 'Pt #1' with a lowercase 't'

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm